# Limiting with a big value the number of characters in a div (with paste prevent)

Tags: jquery, css

I don't know how to set the maximum number of characters in a div tha works also with the paste action.

I wrote this that works, but if I paste something it displays also if the number of character is at limit.

```
<div id="faketxt" contentEditable=true data-text="Write Here"  onkeypress="return (this.innerText.length <= 19200)"></div>
```

How can I prevent the paste action?

It's also very important that the limit of the characters has to be 19200. Some of the codes with javascript don't work with a big value.

Comment: I believe that the "onkeypress" event is the problem, try another event.

Comment: wich event for preventig paste and writing?

Comment: Just added an answer, there's an event "paste".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the event is "onkeypress", the copy-paste option is a kind of a bypass. Luckily for you - there's a `paste` event, so simply bind a function to that event that checks if the pasted content's length is legit according to your requirements.
Something like this:

```
$("#faketxt").bind("paste", function(e){
    var pastedData = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text');
    if(pastedData.length > 19200) return false;
    if(pastedData.length + $(this).text().length > 19200) return false;
    return true;
} );
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/vf4xrdfu/4/)

Comment: Amm... it should, Can you please create a jsfiddle?

Comment: There was a typo in the variable's name and in the jsfiddle the jquery library wasn't included - **fixed**, here: https://jsfiddle.net/vf4xrdfu/2/

Comment: It works, try to paste a string that has more than 19200 characters and it won't paste it.

Comment: Try to paste 1 "d" more; you will see that doesn't work

Comment: Got it - minor modification, 2 min

Comment: Added another condition that checks if the length of the current text **plus** the about to be pasted text is still in the range.

Comment: Yes, but If the text that I want to paste is bigger tha 19200 characters it doesn't paste anything. How can I paste the first 19200 characters?

Comment: You should first calculate how many characters left and then use **substring(0,X)** to get the X first characters of the string.

Comment: Can you write it please? Or I have to create another question? In all cases I'm going to tick your answer...